# Angular ngFor doesn't seem to work right in ClojureScript

Tags: html, angular, clojure, clojurescript

I have next problem with Angular, ClojureScript combination:

```
<select #grocery >
  <option value="-1" > - Select - </option>
  <option *ngFor="#groceryOp of groceries();" value="{{getGroceryId(groceryOp)}}">{{getGroceryName(groceryOp)}}</option>
</select>
```

This is what is generated:

```
<select>
  <option value="-1"> - Select - </option>
  <!--template bindings={}-->
  <option>test</option>
  <option>test1</option>
</select>
```

Notice there is no value attribute in second and third option.
Why is that?

This is my namespace:
[GitHub repository cljs namespace](https://github.com/VladimirMarkovic86/personal-organiser/blob/master/src/cljs/personal_organiser/meal/jsmeal.cljs)

```
Angular version is "2.0.0-beta.14".
Clojure version is 1.8.
ClojureScript vesion is 1.7.170.
```